# List of installed programs without running a program in the system

Tags: linux-mint, package-management, logs, dpkg

My Linux Mint 15 broke and there seems to be no way to fix it.
I cannot boot it so I haven't got access to the terminal. What I'm going to do is make a backup of `/home` with a flash disk running Mint (done that) and reinstall Mint -> restoring `/home`, but I'd like to get a list of installed programs so I can reinstall them. I know:

```
dpkg --get-selections
```

exists, but that requires running the program from within the system, which I can't do because I can't boot it.

Is there any way to get the list or send the command from the Mint from the flash disk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### /var/log/dpkg.log*

You could also just mount the parition that contains root (`/`) and copy the files `/var/log/dpkg.log*`. These files will contain all the applications that were installed on your system.

Just grep through the files looking for the word "installed":

```
$ grep " installed" dpkg.log*|tail -5
dpkg.log.1:2013-09-06 21:29:36 status installed libopenipmi0:amd64 2.0.18-0ubuntu4
dpkg.log.1:2013-09-06 21:29:36 status installed openipmi:amd64 2.0.18-0ubuntu4
dpkg.log.1:2013-09-06 21:29:36 status installed ipmitool:amd64 1.8.11-5ubuntu1
dpkg.log.1:2013-09-06 21:29:36 status installed ureadahead:amd64 0.100.0-12build1
dpkg.log.1:2013-09-06 21:29:37 status installed libc-bin:amd64 2.15-0ubuntu20
```

You can filter this output down to the actual package name + version:

```
$ grep " installed" dpkg.log*|awk '{print $5, $6}'|head -5
man-db:amd64 2.6.3-1
ureadahead:amd64 0.100.0-12build1
bamfdaemon:amd64 0.3.4-0ubuntu1
desktop-file-utils:amd64 0.20-0.1ubuntu1
gnome-menus:amd64 3.6.0-0ubuntu1
```

#### dpkg .list files

Also you can get the list of `.list` files, which are the names of the packages installed:

```
$ ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list | head -5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    628 Oct 17  2012 /var/lib/dpkg/info/account-plugin-aim.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    868 Oct  6 02:44 /var/lib/dpkg/info/account-plugin-facebook.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    802 Oct  6 02:44 /var/lib/dpkg/info/account-plugin-flickr.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    840 Oct  6 02:44 /var/lib/dpkg/info/account-plugin-google.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    936 Oct  6 02:44 /var/lib/dpkg/info/account-plugin-icons.list
```

To show all the installed applications just remove `| head -5` which shows the first 5 results.

Comment: Simple and working! Works correctly!

Answer (score 3):

I tested this with an Ubuntu 13.10 partition but it should equally work for Mint,

Boot from the flash disk, mount your Mint partition, chroot to it and then run the command.

E.g. (as root):

```
mkdir /mnt/mint 
mount /dev/sdXY /mnt/mint  # where sdXY is the partition where you have Mint installed
chroot /mnt/mint
dpkg --get-selections
```

Comment: dpkg(1)'s `--admindir` option can allow you to avoid a chroot(1). `dpkg --admindir=/path/to/systems/var/lib/dpkg --get-selections`.

Answer (score 0):

List all the log files of `dpkg`:

```
ls /var/log/dpkg.log* -ltr
```

The older log files are saved as `.gz`

Check in both

```
grep  " installed" /var/log/dpkg.log* | grep <pattern>
zgrep " installed" /var/log/dpkg.log* | grep <pattern>
```